# function in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two scenarios. The first one is fast, but not an option. The second one uses a function and kills the indexing. The values would look similar to this 'ww,tt,tt,bb'. They can put as many codes as they want. Is there a better approach than using the function? This is a stored proc using server 2008.

Without Function:

```
WHERE  date BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20140731' and 
LEFT(id, 2) IN ('wp')
```

With Function:

```
WHERE  date BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20140731' and 
LEFT(id, 2) IN (SELECT* FROM Toolbox.dbo.Split_DelimitedString_fn(@string,',') )
```

Comment: What version of *SQL Server*? and what does `Split_DelimitedString_fn` look like?

Comment: Is this within a procedure?

Comment: Yes, within a procedure using server 2008.

Comment: Why is it a single string with commas in the first place?

Comment: This comes from an ssrs report. I have no option for  how it comes. It just comes as a string that I have to parse.

Comment: Fuzzy matches on strings are hard to optimize, proper usages of indexes require deterministic comparisons which LEFT, SUBSTRING, and LIKE will not provide.  The bulk of your index improvements will come from filtering other fields.  You could use a persisted calculated field for the first two characters and add an index.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to split the string before hand and insert the result into a temp table:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
   SELECT   *
   FROM     Toolbox.dbo.Split_DelimitedString_fn(@string,',')
```

Then rewrite your query as

```
WHERE  date BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20140731' and 
LEFT(id, 2) IN (SELECT * FROM #tmp)
```

Comment: I've already tried this, still just as slow as using the function.

Comment: The problem is with `LEN(id,2)`: SQL Server won't know which row satisfy the condition until it has run the function through all rows, hence a Clustered Index Scan will be selected. How about putting an index on the query and change it to `id LIKE 'wd%'`. Also can you post your execution plan?

Comment: instead of doing this in the `where` clause, you should join to `#tmp` eg: `join #tmp t on t.<Value> = left(id,2)`

Comment: May not make a difference. SQL Server will rewrite it to a `JOIN` most of the time. That's why I asked for the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question correctly you want to have the 'in' clause be dynamically determined by what is in another table.

Have you tried:

```
WHERE  date BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20140731' and 
LEFT(id, 2) IN (SELECT <column> FROM Toolbox.dbo.tblname)
```

Second attempt:
move the Left(id,2) into the select  clause and then filter on that columns

```
select 
   <current query>
   ,Left(id,2) as sort
from
   <current query>
WHERE  date BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20140731' and 
sort IN (SELECT* FROM Toolbox.dbo.Split_DelimitedString_fn(@string,',') )
```

Comment: @user3897860 what does the string typically look like?

Comment: @user3897860 Have you tried moving the 'left(id, 2) into the select  clause? Use an alias and then filter on that alias?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a table variable, and insert the values:

```
DECLARE @SplitIds TABLE
(
  SplitId varchar(10)
)

Insert into @SplitIds (SplitIds)
SELECT field FROM Toolbox.dbo.Split_DelimitedString_fn(@string,',')
```

You could then join against this table...

```
SELECT columns
FROM TableName a INNER JOIN @SplitIds b ON LEFT(id, 2) = b.SplitId
WHERE a.date BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20140731'
```

Not sure if this will speed the query up, but you can use the Execution plan to help and also check your **indexes**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the performance issue centers on how to efficiently split the CSV string in SQL. If so [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298) on how to employ [Jeff Moden's *Tally-Ho CSV Splitter*](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) might be the ticket. Repeated here for clarity:

Function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH E1(N) AS (
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
       ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows for
                     -- both performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
            SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() 
                                                        OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just
                     -- once for each delimiter)
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
        ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
            SELECT s.N1,
                   ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
            FROM cteStart s
        )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final
     -- element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
go
```

Example usage from previous answer;

```
with data as (
    select Code,Location,Quantity,Store from ( values
        ('L698-W-EA',          NULL,                                      2, 'A')
       ,('L82009-EA',          'A1K2, A1N2, C4Y3, CBP2',                  2, 'A')
       ,('L80401-A-EA',        'A1S2, SHIP, R2F1, CBP5, BRP, BRP1-20',    17,'A')
       ,('CWD2132W-BOX-25PK',  'A-AISLE',                                 1, 'M')
       ,('GM22660003-EA',      'B1K2',                                    1, 'M')
    )data(Code,Location,Quantity,Store)
)
,shredded as (
    select Code,Location,Quantity,Store,t.*
    from data
    cross apply [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](data.Location,',') as t
)
select 
    pvt.Code,pvt.Quantity,pvt.Store
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[1],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc1
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[2],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc2
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[3],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc3
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[4],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc4
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[5],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc5 
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[6],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc6
from shredded
pivot (max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) pvt;
;
go
```

yielding:

```
Code              Quantity    Store Loc1     Loc2     Loc3     Loc4     Loc5     Loc6
----------------- ----------- ----- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
L698-W-EA         2           A                                                   
L82009-EA         2           A     A1K2      A1N2     C4Y3     CBP2              
L80401-A-EA       17          A     A1S2      SHIP     R2F1     CBP5     BRP      BRP1-20
CWD2132W-BOX-25PK 1           M     A-AISLE                                       
GM22660003-EA     1           M     B1K2
```